# How to change float to date type in python? (ValueError: day is out of range for month)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following column:

```
0       3012022.0
1       3012022.0
2       3012022.0
3       3012022.0
4       3012022.0
          ...    
351    24032022.0
352    24032022.0

df.Data = df.Data.astype('str')
```

I converted the float to string and I'm trying to transform them in datetype:

```
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], format='%d%m%Y'+'.0').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

output:
ValueError: day is out of range for month

the code is:

```
os.chdir('/home/carol/upload')
for file in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    xls = pd.ExcelFile('/home/carol/upload/%s'%(file))
    
    if len(xls.sheet_names) > 1:
        list_sheets= []
        for i in xls.sheet_names:
            df = pd.read_excel(xls, i)
            list_sheets.append(df)
        df = pd.concat(list_sheets)
    else:
        df = pd.read_excel(xls)

    df = df[['Data','Frota','Placa','ValorFrete', 'ValorFaturado','CodFilial','NomeFilial']]
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
    df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
    df.columns = df.columns.str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8')
    df= df.apply(lambda x: x.str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8'))

    df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'].astype(str).str.split('\.').str[0], format='%d%m%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to string, remove the decimal point and coerce to datettime. Code as follows

```
 df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'].astype(str).str.split('\.').str[0], format='%d%m%Y')



    data
0   2022-01-30
1   2022-01-30
2   2022-01-30
3   2022-01-30
4   2022-01-30
351 2022-03-24
352 2022-03-24
```

Comment: it continues to give me " day is out of range for month"

Comment: Unless you provided a sample dataset that is not representative of your situation. You can see with your sample I extracted it out. Are you using my code as is or  you are making additions?

Comment: I updated with my code, maybe I'm doing something wrong! I used your code

Comment: run with a short dataset, the one you provided and check. That will help you identify where issues are, Unless I am provided with additional data I am unable to improve my code to cater for your situation